# How can I print particular set of pages like 1,3,5,6,9... using lp command

Tags: linux, command-line, lpr

I am trying to print particular set of pages using `lp` command, but page-ranges option is not getting me the exact pages.

```
lpr -o page-ranges=1,3,5,6,9 filename
```

Comment: You could try lp instead of lpr, `lp -P 1,3,5,6,9 filename`

Answer (score 0):

lp knows the option -P to set a page list

> -P page-list
>
> Specifies which pages to print in the document. The list can contain a list of numbers and ranges (#-#) separated by commas (e.g. 1,3-5,16). The page numbers refer to the output pages and not the document's original pages - options like "number-up" can affect the numbering of the pages.

Comment: can u please give me one example, didn't understand this sentence "The page numbers refer to the output pages and not the document's original pages"

Comment: I don't know lp that much, but it means, that if you switch the pages (that last page. comes first) the -P option affects the pages how they would come out of the printer, not how they are in the document

Comment: Thanks for the info.. I want to print the pages how they are available in the document(PCL file).

Comment: then I don't think you will have got any problems with the option....

Answer (score 0):

There's a linux utility that will help you with this task called `seq`.

See:

```
echo $(seq -f "%g," 1 2 10) # prints all odd numbers from 1 to 10
lp -P $(seq -f "%g," 1 2 10) filename.pdf  # prints odd pages from 1 to 10 of filename.pdf
```

Read `seq --help` to learn more :D